# Mongodb how to insert with long string key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

In my situation, I need url to be an unique index, but some urls can be very large which exceed mongodb max key length, thus return error,

```
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 17280,
        "errmsg" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 17280 Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing test.temp.$_id_ 2953 { : \"iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii...\" }"
    }
})
```

Is there any way/ alternative method/ trick /anything which I could store url as unique index?

Comment: You can store a hash of url as a key, and the url itself as a value. Hash has fixed length. Collisions will be extremely rare.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on stalks comment, you can use collision resistant hash function (sha-256) to store the hash of your url this way you can guarantee it to have fixed length and also have high probability of being unique (I remember that you can win something if you will find 2 sha different keys mapping to the same value).

If you really need to store url as well - put them in a separate (not indexed field). Another suggestion is to try to use [hashed index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-hashed/) instead of the normal index (can not try it right now, so please tell how it goes)